# Using 'get' to transfer contents of folders using smbclient

Tags: linux, raspbian, file-transfer, smb, smbclient

Using smbclient and the 'get' command to move files from a Windows network share over to a Linux box.  I can smbclient from Linux to the network share and bring individual files over by doing something like:

```
smb: \Source\> get 'filename.txt'
```

This automatically drops the file into whatever current directory I'm in on Linux - which is perfect.

**My question is:** How do I stage a bunch of files on the network share, and then when I'm ready, transfer all of the files at once?

Hoping I don't have to name every individual file I want to transfer.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the `get` command in a code block (select it in the editor and click the `{}` button). Also it may improve readability by moving the question to the end.

Answer (score 1):

In smbclient's built-in special purpose shell,

```
recurse ON
mget *
```

will recursively get all files.

Note that there's no real reason to memorize the slightly awkwardish smbclient commands; you can just *mount* the share and copy files from there as if they were on a local storage medium. Then, you can work without smbclient, but simply `cp -r /point/where/you/mounted/the/share/* ./` to copy all files from there to the current directory.

Comment: If using the smbclient commands, the `mask` command can also be used in combination with `recurse` and `mget` to provide additional filtering control during recursive operations, as explained in detail in `man smbclient`.

Comment: Thanks all, this is what I need.  I'm trying to mirror what I'd see in the field so I will go the mounting route.  Next up, how to mount a share on Linux!

Comment: Mounting SMB requires root, while smbclient does not. That might be a reason to use smbclient instead of a mount ;-)

Comment: @stackprotector very true!